# How to force ttkbootstrap TableView column title to always stay right justified

Tags: tableview, ttkbootstrap

I've created a ttkbootstrap tableview with several columns where one column title/heading is configured to be right justified. When data is loaded the column title/heading is no longer right justified.

I've used Treeview before and when refreshing data column headings always kept their configuration. Using  ttkbootstrap TableView this doesn't seem to be the case.

I am using the `build_table_data` method to update the TableView with data. According to the documentation this method will completely rebuild the underlying table with the new column and row data. I confirmed I am providing the same column config as I do when creating the TableView. but for some reason the column heading is no longer right justified.

The following code can reproduce the problem. When run you will see a column heading "Right Just" which is right justified. Press the test button and data is loaded, and the heading is no longer right justified. Is this a bug or expected behavior. Any suggestions on how to get around the feature.

```
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.tableview import Tableview

def loaddata():
    eobTable_data = [('Rec 1', '', 'a', 'Col4 data', '')]
    eobTable.build_table_data(coldata=eobColms,rowdata=eobTable_data)


# create the toplevel window
root = ttk.Window()
frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frame.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
global eobColms
eobColms = [{'text': 'Col 1', 'anchor': 'w', 'stretch': False},
    {'text': 'Col 2', 'stretch': True},
    {'text': 'Col 3', 'anchor': 'w','stretch': False},
    {'text': 'Right Just','anchor': 'e', 'stretch': False},
    {'text': 'Col 5', 'stretch': True}]

eobTable_data = ("",)
eobTable = Tableview(root,coldata=eobColms,rowdata=eobTable_data, paginated=True,pagesize=14,searchable=True,bootstyle='danger',height=14)
eobTable.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

test_btn = ttk.Button(root,text="Test",command=loaddata).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Further digging into the documentation there is an attribute 'autoalign' which I need to set to false when creating the TableView